# Error when nodejs app in a docker container tries to connect to mongodb in a different docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm trying to get my nodejs API running in a docker container to connect to a mongodb running in a different container.

When I run the command `docker ps` I get this output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
2ad1f567f713        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago         Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
```

I then ran this command `docker run --publish 3000:3000 --name my-api my-api:1.0`, but that gave me this time out error

```
(node:37) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

I then tried this command  `docker run --publish 3000:3000 --net 2ad1f567f713:mongodb --name my-api my-api:1.0`, but that gave this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network 2ad1f567f713:mongodb not found.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to [`docker network create` a network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks), then `docker run --net ...` both containers on that same network.  If you use Docker Compose to launch the containers, [it will create a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DavidMaze links, I did the following:

First, in my `my-api` nodejs code, I had to change my `.env` file from

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://@127.0.0.1:27017/hellodatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

to

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://@mongodb:27017/hellodatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Notice the `@mongodb` which I intend to use as a container name later on in my answer.

Then I did

```
// start network called hello-network
docker create network hello-network;
// start mongo database on the hello-network, run in background, mount database to my localhost drive /data/db, and also call this instance mongodb to match my earlier .env file
docker run -it --publish 27017:27017 --network hello-network -v mongodata:/data/db --name mongodb -d mongo;
// start my-api on the hello-network, in the background
docker run -it --publish 3000:3000 --network hello-network -d --name my-api my-api:1.0;
```